# Extract numbers from alphanumaric string in Android

Tags: java, android, string, substring, alphanumeric

I have an alphanumaric string i want to get only the numbers from that alphanumaric string. Like i have a

```
string S = Call forwarding [112234]& Multiparty [434566] & Caller line identification[12345]&.
```

I want to get the string as

```
string S = 112234 & 434566 &12345 &
```

so that I can split this string with "&" and pupulate a listview using arrayadapter. 
currently I am using this method and it shows aphanumaric string like S in first case I want to be it in secound case. 
Here is my code.

```
String[] list={};
String ServerResponse = response.toString();
Log.d("Curretnts", "Server response"+ServerResponse);
list =ServerResponse.split("&");
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract numbers from string using regex.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Call forwarding [112234]& Multiparty [434566] & Caller line identification[12345]&.");

while (m.find())
  System.out.println(m.group());
```

In your example you need to add found items to `String[] list={};`.

Comment: thanks for the help. What if I want to get only alphabets instead of numbers what shoul be replaced with ("\\d+")?

Comment: Suggest you to check out some regex tutorials for simple pattern matching http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html or http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm